# Loop through all views in Lotus Notes with Excel VBA script

Tags: vba, loops, view, lotus-notes

I have a script (found on the web and adjusted to my needs) that can access a specific view of Lotus Notes, pick up some info from each email and save any attachment to a given folder. If I want to do this for more views I currently have the names of these views in my worksheet and loop through them.
What I would like to do is to loop through all views and do the same.

I am not a professional developer and not yet entirely familiar working with objects. This problem however is to complicated for me. The Lotus Notes object is also not the easiest to understand.

I am using the following code which of course is part of a larger (working) script. For starters it would be enough to just be able to loop through all views and print the Name of the view. From there on I think I can do the rest myself.
Can anyone adjust the code to make it work.

```
Public Sub Get_Notes_Email_Text()

Dim NSession As Object      'NotesSession
Dim NMailDB As Object       'NotesDatabase
Dim NDocs As Object         'NotesDocumentCollection
Dim NDoc As Object          'NotesDocument
Dim NNextDoc As Object      'NotesDocument
Dim view As String

'Start a Lotus Notes session
Set NSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
'Connect to the Lotus Notes database
 Set NMailDB = NSession.GetDatabase("", "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\AppData\Local\IBM\Notes\Data\mail\" & Environ("Username") & ".nsf") 'Default server en database
If Not NMailDB.IsOpen Then
    NMailDB.OpenMail
End If

'Loop through all views and print .Name tot Immediate Window

'    Dim Map As Variant
'    Dim Mappen As Object
'    Set Mappen = NMailDB.Views
'
'    For Each Map In Mappen
'        Debug.Print Map.Name
'    Next Map
'
End Sub
```

Comment: All you have shown us here is some commented-out code. We'll be happy to help you debug your code, because that helps you learn. We're a lot less happy to write code for you. So tell us -- what happens when you remove those comments and try to run the code?

Answer (score 0):

Easier than going through all views is to just go to one view that shows all documents.  If it is a mail database, then the view is called "($All)"

```
Set allDocsView = NMailDB.getView("($All)")
allDocsView.autoUpdate = false
```

You can then loop through the documents in the view using

```
Set docToProcess = allDocsView.GetFirstDocument
While Not ( docToProcess Is Nothing )
    'Do what you plan to do here
Set docToProcess = allDocsView.GetNextDocument( docToProcess )
Wend
```

UPDATE:
As you want to loop through Folders, not views, you need to do something like the following

```
Dim sess As New notessession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim views As Variant

Set db = sess.CurrentDatabase

views = db.Views
Forall v In views
    If v.isFolder Then ' Needed so that we are only processing Folder objects and not views - you will need to check that you are not processing system folders e.g. $Inbox etc
        'Do your processing of documents here
    End If
End Forall
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Rob. I know how to use the $All view. One thing that I think doesn't cover this solution is that I want to know in what view the actual email is stored. Unless there is a property that would show the real view (and not just $All) the email is stored in. I use that name in the name of each attachment. Besides that I would be interested to see if looping through all the view would also mean looping through all sub-views and getting these names too.

Comment: As long as you are aware that individual NotesDocuments can and do appear in more than one view at the same time.  From your comment, it looks as though you are wanting to loop through folders instead of views (you talk about sub views).  Inbox is a folder as are the ones created by the end user.  Folders and views are different things.  A document can only ever be in one folder at a time.  Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to do, and then I can provide more pointers.

Comment: I am indeed trying to loop through al the different views and subviews. And yes I am aware that e-mails appear in more than one view. This knowledge let to changing our way of deleting e-mails. Previously we would delete an entire view. Now we delete the content of the view and then the view. This way the e-mails are also no longer shown in the $All view.

Comment: After re-reading your comment I am not entirely sure if my answer is what I am looking for. What I would like to do is to loop through all the e-mails present in a folder/view created by the user. I wasn’t really aware of the difference between views and folders. And their subs. The fact that an e-mail can appear in more than one view is not really important. So I guess I would like to loop through (sub) folders.

Comment: Update the answer - you should update your question too: it will help folk searching in the future

Comment: The code you provided works just fine now. I now can loop through folders only or through both views and folders. Both results are very interesting since I get more names than expected. I am trying to update my question as you suggested but am struggling how.

Comment: Struggling?  You should write the question stating what you are trying to do, what you have done, what you expect to get, and indicate which parts aren't working.  In this case you want to loop through each folder and do "something".  Tell us what that something is in your question.